# Can I treat Varbinary and bytea fields equivalently?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, varbinary

I moved a mysql DB to Postgres, but some of the tables had a `varbinary(16)` field (to store an ip address).

Postgres does not support `varbinary` fields, and after some research, I found that the Postgres equivalent is `bytea`.

So, I went ahead and made tables with `bytea` as the field type for the ip columns.

Now, I am not sure, but this *might* be causing me problems.

So, now my question is if `bytea` and `varbinary` can be treated totally equally or not. 
For example, if the original MySQL query is:

```
 INSERT INTO messages(userID, userName, userRole, dateTime, ip, text)
 Values('21212111','bot','4',NOW(), inet_pton($ip), 'hi');
```

Note: I included some php in there, because my logs don't show what the inserted ip address is (It's a blob/something)

Now, would this query store the exact same data if it was a `bytea` field instead? I would presume yes, but does the same hold true for a select statement?
i.e. Would, this query return the same data regardless of whether the ip field was `varbinary` or `bytea`?

```
SELECT userID, userName, userRole, channel ,ip FROM table
```

Thanks for your time, have a good day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `bytea` is an equivalent to `varbinary`/`image`/`blob` et al. Having said that, PostgreSQL does come with an `inet` type as standard, which will take an IPv4 address in textual representation and store it as a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Exactly, use INET for ip adresses. Works for IPv6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you have to use `pg_escape_bytea()` and `pg_unescape_bytea()` functions.

Comment: So, you use `pg_escape_bytea()` when you are inserting a query, and when `pg_unescape_bytea` when you are parsing a query?

Comment: You don't need pg_escape_bytea() when using the correct datatype, INET in this case. Use pg_query_params() or pg_send_query_params() for your SQL and parameters to avoid SQL injection to keep things simple.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, the question was about handling `bytea` field, not about which type to use. And IIRC the `bytea` handling in php is somewhat awkward, there were some difficulties with using it with parametrized queries, but I don't remember the details.

Comment: @ Michael Krelin - hacker: Correct, but the question came up because the wrong datatype is used. Fix the real problem, not the work around.

Comment: Frank, I find your suggestion entirely valid, but I do not know enough of OP circumstances and prospects to leave him without an answer to the question he actually asked ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Postgres does not support varbinary fields, and after some research, I
>   found that the Postgres equivalent is bytea.
>
> So, I went ahead and made tables with bytea as the field type for the
>   ip columns.

INET is made for ip-addresses, IPv4 and IPv6, bytea is made for binary data. Always use the best matching datatype, PostgreSQL has many great datatypes. And you can create your own datatypes (TYPE or DOMAIN), if you want to. But never abuse bytea just because you can.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdomain.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html